# If I want to use Amazon DynamoDB as database for my mobile app, which Ec2 instance I can opt for?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use dynamoDB as the database for my mobile application. If EC2 instance will perform well, if my mobile application has following:

- 100k daily active users
- 1 million daily active users
- 10 million active users

I am new to AWS ecosystem and i am unable to figure out which instance to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DynamoDb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html) is **serverless** service, which means that you do not need to provision any EC2 instances to host the database. Its all managed by AWS.

> DynamoDB lets you **offload the administrative burdens of operating and scaling** a distributed database so that you don't have to worry about hardware provisioning, setup and configuration, replication, software patching, or cluster scaling.

The only thing that you have to consider is setting up its [read/write](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html) capacity. However, if you are not sure on this as well, you can use [on-demand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.OnDemand) capacity mode:

> Amazon DynamoDB on-demand is a flexible billing option capable of serving thousands of requests per second **without capacity planning**. DynamoDB on-demand offers pay-per-request pricing for read and write requests so that you **pay only for what you use**.

Comment: ,Thankyou verymuch for taking time to reply to my issue. As per ur answer, it means that I need not to pay anything for EC2 instance, I need to pay for writes and reads. i.e , if I make 100 million writes(100*1.5$), is it, and can It handle more than 1million simultaneous connections, if I integrate into flutter app, I am using flutter to develop an mobile application??

Comment: @I'mSunil3 Hi. No problem. That's correct. You can read more about pricing of DynamoDB [here](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/).

Comment: @I'mSunil3 Yes. Its the entire point of serverless architectures. They will scale automatically for you. But obviously the more they scale the more you have to pay.

Comment: thank you very much for making to clear to understand, your answer is accepted, and please let me know, if I flutter can handle more than 1 million simultaneous connections, with dynamoDB.

Comment: @I'mSunil3 Yes. AWS make it [clear](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/): "DynamoDB are its ability to scale reliably to **millions of concurrent** users and requests" :-)

Comment: Thankyou very much, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052340/i-am-using-digital-ocean-cloud-storage-and-i-want-to-migrate-to-aws-s3