# I am using digital ocean cloud storage, and I want to migrate to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, storage

I am using digital ocean spaces as a cloud storage to store users data, and its costing me for both hosting the data and for datatransfer. So, I wanna migrate to Amazon Simple storage s3 (frequent access). I just went through the official docs of AWS S3 and found that, it will cost only for the data hosted in their storage, regardless of the retrieval numbers, I am new to AWS ecosystem and I am not sure about the pricing concept of AWS. Please let me know the pricing estimate for the following scenario:

```
=> any user can upload a data in my mobile applications
=> if i store around 100 gb of data with AWS s3,
=> if i retrieve that 100 gb around 50 to 100 times a day in my mobile app.
=> how much I need to pay per month, 
=> current pricing to store 1 gb is around $0.02.($0.02/1gb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what documentation you were reading, but the [official S3 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) is pretty clear that you are charged for:

- Data storage, which depends on region but is somewhere between 2 and 5 US cents per gigabyte, per month.
- Number of requests, which again depends on region, but is on the order of a few US cents per 1,000 requests (retrieving a file is a GET request; uploading a file is a PUT request).
- Data transfer, which again depends on region, but ranges from a low of $0.09/GB in the US regions, to a high (I think) of $0.154 in the Capetown region.

So, if you're retrieving 100 GB of data 100 times a day, you will be paying data transfer costs of anywhere from $900 to $1540 *per day*.

In my experience, Digital Ocean tends to be cheaper than AWS for most things (but you get fewer features). However, if you're really transferring 10 TB of data per day (I think that's unlikely, but it's what you asked), you should look for some hosting service that offers unlimited bandwidth.

Comment: Thankyou verymuch for answering my issue, actually I am new to this AWS ecosystem and not able to figure out the pricing algorithm. What you said is correct, I read something similar to that, but, in some other documentation, I read that data transfer cost will be applied to only, Amazon S3(infrequent access storage) and for AWS(frequent access), only data storage cost will be applied. Are you sure that, data. transfer cost will be applied, in both cases. Please let me know.

Comment: @I'mSunil3 - I don't know what "other documentation" you read, but either it's incorrect or you misunderstood it. I can assure you that S3 does have data transfer charges, and they can be significant.

Comment: Thankyou very much for making it clear to figure out, I will continuing with digital ocean itself  ,https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/ actually I read that retrieval fee is N/A for s3 standard, so I thought that, there will be no fee for data transferred, now I understood that retrieval and data transfer are quite different, and retrieval fee is applicable for infrequent access storage type.

Comment: your answer is accepted, and another thing I wanna ask is that if I use cloud front to retrieve media files , do I need to pay every time, I retrieve the same data into my app(i.e. that same movie 1000 time a day = I need to pay retrieval charge * 1000 time, is it?).is It same with s3 as well, or any method to reduce the transfer charges in AWS. Thank you

Comment: Estimated data stored in cloud is :

daily 50000 uploads and each upload is of 20 mb => 20 MB * 50000 => 976 gb

daily 200000 retrievals , each retrieved object size is 20 MB => 200000 * 20 MB = > 3904 gb,                                                                                                                                           if possible, check this this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63081269/can-i-use-godaddy-cloud-to-store-media-files-uploaded-by-our-app-users-if-not